# Client-side error when attempting to delete own question

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete

My question has no answers, only a comment.

The button seems completely unresponsive and does not delete it. I remember that a while ago I was able to delete all my questions.

For example, I have a question which got hit by downvotes and was put on hold.

When it closed I had -3 votes. Today I had -5 and that made me lose all of my rep.

This also seems stupid. If the question was closed, what's the point of keeping the votes working?

Comment: If it is negatively voted and has no positively voted answers, it'l be deleted eventually.

Comment: The point is deleting it immediately, as it may be a dumb question that I'd like to remove or a question which is constantly getting downvotes. Waiting months while getting the first 3 days loads of downvotes doesn't seem fair.

Comment: i mean... maybe try to learn from the experience so that you don't find yourself in this situation again? What was so wrong with the question that it's getting downvotes? Can it be improved?

Comment: Nope. Improving it would mean changing the question entirely, which should be called 'vandalization' here on SO.

Comment: @KevinB Lookint at OP profile, I guess it is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277182/how-do-i-slowly-accelerate-in-python it can be improved, users said it lacks details for an answer, so add some?

Comment: that's not entirely accurate. Yes, some changes to a post can be considered vandalism, but you can improve a post without crossing that line.

Comment: Regardless, if you can't delete it, there must be something of value still linked to it. Care to provide a link?

Comment: @MarkKirby nope, the question is on the physics stack exchange. Editing that would effectively mean changing the whole context. Also, if you read that, there's no point in doing so as I have nothing to ask.

Comment: @rene I can't delete that unfortunately.

Comment: This one then? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405619/is-it-possible-that-quantum-entanglement-has-an-hidden-variable

Comment: @MarkKirby Yes. I can't delete that either.

Comment: @rene correct, but I still can't delete them.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors, please, and post any that you find. This appears to be failing client-side.

Comment: @Shog9 This is the only thing I get : `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js”.` I am using Firefox quantum. The warning is caused by uBlock. Disabling it doesn't work either.

Comment: Just edited my previous comment. As said, it's my Adblocker. Disabling it won't work either.

Comment: Nope. No errors.

Comment: Ok, try this for me please - go to the question you want deleted, and paste the following into your browser console: `$.post("/posts/" + (window.location.pathname.match(/\/questions\/(\d+)\//)[1]) + "/vote/10", {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey})`

Comment: @Shog9 That works wonderfully.

Comment: This is definitely a client-side failure then (the actual deletion route is working, and nothing is blocking the request). Any chance you could get a screencapture of the delete link failing? I've been trying to reproduce this without success.

Comment: Do you mean actually recording me pressing the delete button?

Comment: yes, if you have that option. LICEcap works pretty well if you're on Windows.

Comment: Here you go https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Xq4iUCKtI